# Can I catch stored procedure return values in other stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Assuming I have the following stored procedure:

```
delimiter @@
create procedure test1(In n1 int, In n2 int)
begin
  select n1,n2
end @@
```

then I want to run it several times from other stored proc:

```
delimiter @@
create procedure test2()
begin
  call test1(1,2);
  call test1(3,4);
end @@
```

Assuming `test1` is fixed and I can't change it (to function or out parameter), how can I get the result of `test1` in `test2` and block it from returning every results of `test1` to the caller?

is it possible?

I want to run the proc a million times and the results are slowing down the whole process...

Comment: Can you not just insert the resulting output from your stored procedures into a temp table (i know this is possible with MS SQL but not sure with mySql) and then do whatever you need to from that temp table?

Comment: @DavidShorthose I can't select a `procedure` only `function`...

Comment: No, you cannot catch/use/block a resultset inside mysql. Since test1 cannot be modified, you have to make a copy of it and use that instead.

Comment: @Solarflare thanks a lot